# iOS: Example seed template project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Is there a good iOS seed template project that includes all the common design patterns and accepted practices in the Cocoa/iOS community? Something that includes an MVC file structure, AFNetworking, MBProgressHud, as well as commonly used helpers?

With Ruby on Rails as well as Express Node.js, there is a command to generate a new project that already includes all the commonly used gems (equivalent to cocoa pods) and directory structure that is common to all Express/RoR apps.

I know that iOS is NOT as standardized and conventionalized, but is there something like that for iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apple has sample code for developers on their website on many topics. Probably what you want. "Adventure" is an extensive game that would have mvc. I don't know about the other stuff.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/#section=Resource%20Types&topic=Sample%20Code